# How can a case class of strings be converted to a nested hierarchy of Map's efficiently in Scala?

Tags: scala

Assume that the case classes look like:

```
case class X(a: String, b: String, c: String, d: String )
val x = Seq(X("a", "b", "c", "d"), X("a", "b", "p", "q") )
```

What I want is Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, String].

Example: I can use pattern matching to extract the elements and then use groupBy transforms to convert the tuples to Map's.

```
scala> x.map{case X(a,b,c,d) => (a -> (b -> (c, d)))}.groupBy(_._1).map{case (k,v) => (k -> v.map(_._2).groupBy(_._1).map{case (k,v) => (k -> v.map(_._2).groupBy(_._1).flatMap(_._2))})}

res143: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]]] = Map(a -> Map(b -> Map(p -> q, c -> d)))
```

Is there a way to create the nested maps from the case statements other than using groupBy's?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do it in Scala... Which way do you prefer for your case: simplest, most efficient, safest?

Comment: Efficiently. Thanks.

Comment: Scala's maps are slow and [unsafe](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11203), especially immutable. Considers using `java.util.HashMap` which is safe under hash collision attacks and can be wrapped to fit Scala's trait for mutable maps using [`scala.collection.JavaConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html). If you expect only trusted input and can write a wrapper for yourself then for better efficiency you may consider using a map from [HPPC library](https://github.com/carrotsearch/hppc).

Comment: Please provide a sample output of a desired map. It's unclear what should be a key/value in this case.

Comment: I see that non functional requirements are matter for you, so beside code samples of usage and expected results, please, describe your use case in details.